# mongo return document only if value does not present in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a collection, there are docuemnts like below:

```
[
  {
    "item": [
      {"price": 20},
      {"price": 30}
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {"price": 30}
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {"price": 10},
      {"price": 40}
    ]
  },
  {
    "item": [
      {"price": 30},
      {"price": 40}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return the documents where item.price doesnot contain 10 & 20 in any of array element of a document.

The output should be the document with {"item.price:[30]} & {"item.price:[30,40]} as this doesnt contain 10 & 20.

I tried below but unable to find a working query.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/y77IBlyw5rO

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TvhEfQoeOvC

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
  "item.price": {
    $nin: [10,20]
  }
});
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/TvhEfQoeOvC

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "item.price": {
        $nin: [10,20]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_n-GsWrKPx

Comment: This works with find but when I use it in aggregate pipeline using match, it produces wrong output

Comment: Works correctly in aggregation too. https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_n-GsWrKPx

Comment: yes, its working with mongo query and also using java driver but somehow its not giving right output in junit test